# how teste against a list using IF in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have this part of a code, and I cant figure out how to implemente what I want.

```
hostname_negate="SERVER03"
CLUSTER="SERVER01 SERVER02 SERVER03 SERVER04 SERVER05 SERVER06 SERVER07 SERVER08 SERVER09 SERVER10"
for SERVIDOR in $CLUSTER
  do
  If [ $SERVIDOR == $hostname_negate ]; then
  ===SOME ADMINISTRATIVE STUFF HERE ===
  else
  ===SOME ADMINISTRATIVE STUFF HERE===
  fi
  done
```

This work if only one server is in hostname_negate... bute if I have 100 servers and 10 are in hostname_negate.... how I implement this to work?

Comment: You have a typo: You wrote `If` instead of `if`.

Comment: _how I implement this to work?_ What is the goal? Should the condition be true if at least one server is in _negate_, or if all servers are in _negate_? Your question is unclear.

Comment: If one server is in hostname_negate that server canot have the same admin stuff that servers   that do not in hostname_negate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the long run you'll probably be better served having the lists in files instead of strings.

```
CLUSTER="SERVER01 SERVER02 SERVER03 SERVER04 SERVER05 SERVER06 SERVER07 SERVER08 SERVER09 SERVER10"
NEGATES="SERVER03 SERVER07 BROKENSERVER01"

# Convert from string to list in a file.
# Generally better to have these in files instead of strings.
echo "$CLUSTER" | tr ' ' '\n' > /tmp/cluster.$$
echo "$NEGATES" | tr ' ' '\n' > /tmp/negates.$$

for server in $(comm -12 <(sort /tmp/cluster.$$) <(sort /tmp/negates.$$))
do 
    echo "In both lists: $server"
done

for server in $(comm -23 <(sort /tmp/cluster.$$) <(sort /tmp/negates.$$))
do
    echo "Unique to CLUSTER: $server"
done

for server in $(comm -13 <(sort /tmp/cluster.$$) <(sort /tmp/negates.$$))
do
    echo "Unique to NEGATES: $server"
done

# Clean up.
rm /tmp/cluster.$$ /tmp/negates.$$
```

Results in:

```
in both lists: SERVER03
in both lists: SERVER07
unique to CLUSTER: SERVER01
unique to CLUSTER: SERVER02
unique to CLUSTER: SERVER04
unique to CLUSTER: SERVER05
unique to CLUSTER: SERVER06
unique to CLUSTER: SERVER08
unique to CLUSTER: SERVER09
unique to CLUSTER: SERVER10
unique to NEGATES: BROKENSERVER01
```

Comment: tnks, it is perfect

Answer (score 3):

A loop from both the lists, but convert both of them to an array first, something like.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

hostname_negate=(
  "SERVER03" "SERVER07" "SERVER10"
)

cluster=(
  "SERVER01" "SERVER02" "SERVER03" "SERVER04" "SERVER05" "SERVER06" "SERVER07" "SERVER08" "SERVER09" "SERVER10"
)

for servidor in "${cluster[@]}" ; do
  for host_name in "${hostname_negate[@]}"; do
    if [[ $servidor == $host_name ]]; then
      printf '%s %s is a match!\n' "$servidor" "$host_name"
    else
      printf '%s %s does not match!\n' "$servidor" "$host_name"
    fi
  done
done
```

---

Or if you're just trying to check if `hostname_negate` is in `cluster`, then

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

hostname_negate=(
  "SERVER03" "SERVER07" "SERVER10" "SERVER99"
)

cluster=(
  "SERVER01" "SERVER02" "SERVER03"
  "SERVER04" "SERVER05" "SERVER06"
  "SERVER07" "SERVER08" "SERVER09"
  "SERVER10" "SERVER11" "SERVER12"
  "SERVER13" "SERVER14" "SERVER15"
  "SERVER16" "SERVER17" "SERVER18"
  "SERVER19" "SERVER20" "SERVER21"
  "SERVER22" "SERVER23" "SERVER24"
)

cluster_pattern=$(IFS='|'; printf '%s' "@(${cluster[*]})")

for host_name in "${hostname_negate[@]}"; do
  if [[  $host_name == $cluster_pattern ]]; then
    printf '%s is in %s!\n'  "$host_name" $cluster_pattern
  else
    printf '%s is not in %s!\n'  "$host_name" $cluster_pattern
  fi
done
```

Just change the `printf's` to the Administrative stuff that you wanted to do.

Comment: The "cluster_pattern" solution is very nice, and avoids the nested loops.

Comment: Don't quote the whole data inside the array, it should be one element per servername, and not just one whole string. So the quote is one per element and not the whole servernames.

Comment: @glennjackman, thanks for the comment and indeed it is very useful when comparing a lot of strings/pattern.